# HashMap iterator not starting with first key in collection

Tags: java, hashmap, iterator

I'm running into a very strange occurrence where a HashMap variable

```
HashMap<Integer, String> locationCatalog = new HashMap<>();
```

will iterate correctly (ie start at the first numerical key) and sometimes it doesn't. I am iterating through an Excel document (using an external library) to get cell values and, depending on the cell, put it into a HashMap based on the cell's row and column coordinate.

```
locationCatalog.put(row.getRowNum(), cell.getStringCellValue().trim());
```

After all the data is populated, I iterate through locationCatalog to get the contents:

```
Set set = locationCatalog.entrySet();
Iterator trimIterator = set.iterator();
System.out.println(lastLabelName + " - locationCatalog contents (run #1):");
while (trimIterator.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry locationMap = (Map.Entry)trimIterator.next();
    System.out.println("Key: " + (int) locationMap.getKey() + ", Row: " + ((int) locationMap.getKey() + 1) + ", Location: " + locationMap.getValue().toString());
    ...
}
```

Here is a print out of a good run:

```
BALI - locationCatalog contents (run #1):
Key: 16, Row: 17, Location: S082025 E1150531
Key: 17, Row: 18, Location: S082025 E1150531
Key: 18, Row: 19, Location: 
Key: 19, Row: 20, Location: S082025 E1150531
Key: 20, Row: 21, Location:
Key: 21, Row: 22, Location: S082025 E1150531
```

The anomaly occurs sporadically. It seemed to begin when I would move a cell instead of just copy and paste the contents. Once I figured that out, I adjusted the put method to use just an regular integer that was independent of the Excel source. However, this adjustment did not change the outcome. Here is an example of a bad run:

```
BALI - locationCatalog contents (run #1):
Key: 16, Row: 17, Location: S08 20 25 E115 05 31 
Key: 17, Row: 18, Location: 
Key: 18, Row: 19, Location: 
Key: 9, Row: 10, Location: S08 20 25 E115 05 31
Key: 10, Row: 11, Location: S08 20 25 E115 05 31
Key: 11, Row: 12, Location: 
Key: 12, Row: 13, Location: S08 20 25 E115 05 31
Key: 13, Row: 14, Location: 
Key: 14, Row: 15, Location: S08 20 25 E115 05 31
Key: 15, Row: 16, Location: S08 20 25 E115 05 31
```

Without being able to post a screenshot of the Excel file, the cells for this run begin on Row 10 and continue through Row 19. However when it goes through the iteration of locationCatalog, it doesn't start with the lowest key, Key 9 in this case. This is a problem because I have to iterate through this HashMap several times to get a final product and need things to be in an ascending order. After I am finished with the collection, I clear it out to start populating it with a new set of data.

If I cut and paste the same cells into a different row, the outcome (correctly) changes to this:

```
BALI - locationCatalog contents (run #1):
Key: 4, Row: 5, Location: S08 20 25 E115 05 31
Key: 5, Row: 6, Location: S08 20 25 E115 05 31
Key: 6, Row: 7, Location: 
Key: 7, Row: 8, Location: S08 20 25 E115 05 31
Key: 8, Row: 9, Location: 
Key: 9, Row: 10, Location: S08 20 25 E115 05 31
Key: 10, Row: 11, Location: S08 20 25 E115 05 31
Key: 11, Row: 12, Location: S08 20 25 E115 05 31
Key: 12, Row: 13, Location: 
Key: 13, Row: 14, Location:
```

I have been trying for a week now to figure out what is going on, to include changing the parameters of the HashMap, all with no luck. Hopefully someone with more brainpower and Java expertise can lend a helping hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption that `HashMaps` return their entries in some given order is wrong. Use an implementation of `OrderedMap` like `TreeMap` instead.

Comment: @ave8tor maybe something like a tree map... ? like... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

Comment: Thanks for the assist! Turns out it I just had to use TreeMap instead of HashMap to get what I was looking for. It frustrates me that the answer was so simple and I spent an entire week of free time trying everything possible to understand why it was iterating it the way it did.

Comment: @SirDarius thanks for the correction, that was what I meant